# Get image data of known process

Tags: c++, windows, image

For Imageprocessing I want to get all pixel information from a given process.
Concrete its for testing an image hashing algorithm for identifying hearthstone cards, so i need to get a screenshot of the given process.
How can I solve it in windows?
My idea so far:

> 1. Get the process name.
> 2. Get the process ID
> 3. Get Window Handle

I have no idea how to go further from this point.
I hope it understandable what I want to achieve.

Comment: The window handle isn't going to be of much use if the target application uses a rendering API like OpenGL or DirectX. Hearthstone does.

Comment: So what would be the point to start in order to capture it? Thx for your answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no general method for getting the pixels of a particular window that I would be aware of. Depending on how the target application draws itself, this task can be very simple or very complicated. If we were talking about an application that uses good old GDI, then you could just get yourself an HDC to the window via [GetWindowDC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc) and [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt)/[StretchBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) the content over into a bitmap of your own.

Unfortunately, the target application in your case appears to be a game. Games typically use 3D graphics APIs like Direct3D or OpenGL for drawing. Assuming that you cannot simply modify the target application to just send the desired data over to you out of its own free will, the only way to specifically record output from such applications that I'm aware of is to hook into the graphics API and capture the data from underneath the API. This can be done. However, implementing such a system is quite involved. There might be existing libraries to aid with writing such applications, but I don't know any that I could recommend here. If you don't have to capture the game content in real-time, you could just use a screen recording application to, e.g., record a video and then use that video as input for your algorithm. There are also graphics debugging tools like [NSight Graphics](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics) or [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/docs/how/how_import_export.html) that you could use. Be aware that games, particularly online games, these days often have cheat protection systems that are likely to get very angry at you if you attempt to hook into the game…

Apart from all that, one alternative approach might be to use [DXGI Output Duplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) to just capture the entire desktop. While you won't be able to target one specific application (as far as I know), this would potentially have several advantages: First of all, it's only moderately complex to set up compared to a fully-fledged API-hook-based approach. Second, it should work regardless of what API the target application uses and even if the application is in fullscreen mode. Third, since you will have the data delivered straight from the operating system, you shouldn't have any issues with cheat protection. You can use [MonitorFromWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) to get the monitor your target window appears on and then [enumerate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-enumoutputs) all outputs [of all DXGI adapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory-enumadapters) to find the one that corresponds to that HMONITOR…

Comment: thanks for your answer. how is windows10 doing the preview snapshots? is it able to get it via api? because hearthstone does have such a peek preview. otherwise i will take a whole screenshot and crop it to my needs. i found a solution i could transform the hbitmaps to opencv mats. because i will use opencv for the algorithms. Bec

Comment: The operating system (more precisely, the desktop window manager) obviously has access to the contents of any window since it ultimately has to draw the desktop somehow. There actually is an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/thumbnail-ovw) through which you can have DWM paint the thumbnail of a given window into another window. I have never tried this myself, but it might be possible to create a window, have it receive the thumbnail, and then read the thumbnail out of that window you provided…

Comment: @TobiM.Ottorony It's hard to say, however, how such an approach will perform. Also, the thumbnail is probably not necessarily going to be in the full resolution of the source window…